# Delete somebody from your phonebook on SQL through Flask

Tags: sql, flask

This is my code below, but it says the data is deleted but when I check SQL, the data hasn't been touched. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def delete():
    """delete somebody from your phonebook"""



if request.method == "POST":
        firstName = request.form.get("firstName")
        db.execute("DELETE FROM phonebook WHERE id = :user_id AND firstName = :firstName",
        user_id=session["user_id"],
        firstName = firstName)
        flash("contact deleted!")
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        rows = db.execute("""
            SELECT firstName
            FROM phonebook
            WHERE user_id=:user_id
            GROUP BY firstName;
        """, user_id=session["user_id"])
        return render_template("delete.html", firstNames=[row["firstName"] for row in rows])
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Does it require an explicit commit when making changes?

Comment: SQL database but making changes to python and running it through flask. The sql process says it works "DEBUG:cs50:DELETE FROM phonebook WHERE id = 1 AND firstName = 'JO';" but it doesnt actually remove JO from the list

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to commit the change once executed:

```
    # ...
    db.execute("DELETE FROM phonebook WHERE id = :user_id AND firstName = :firstName",
    user_id=session["user_id"],
    firstName = firstName)

    db.commit()
    # ...
```